# Project build issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, ios

I am getting this error while building my project:

_OBJC_CLASS_$_ in .o symbol not found

What could be the potential reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. This was happening because I was using a external library which I was not including while compiling the code though was referring it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Clean all targets (cmd-k) and then build again and see if that message goes away.